# How do you append rows to a table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I was trying to add a row to a table using jQuery, but it is not working.
What might be the reason?

And, can I put in some value to the newly added row..?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('a').click(function() {
            $('#myTable').childs('tr').append('<tr class="child"><td>blahblah<\/td></tr>');
        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    test
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50365764/7186739

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to add this row to the `<tbody>` element, and simply using `append()` on the `<table>` will insert the `<tr>` outside the `<tbody>`, with perhaps undesirable results.

```
$('a').click(function() {
   $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr class="child"><td>blahblah</td></tr>');
});
```

---

**EDIT:** Here is the complete source code, and it does indeed work: (Note the `$(document).ready(function(){});`, which was not present before.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
       $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr class="child"><td>blahblah</td></tr>');
    });
});
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in my experience you cannot modify the html contents of a table.  Try using document.createElement("tr"), and document.appendElement()

Comment: I modified your source so that it should work correctly. (Note the edit above) I didn't notice this before, but you didn't have the `$(document).ready()` included, which basically breaks everything. Unless you wait for the `ready()` event to fire, the DOM isn't loaded and your jQuery selector probably won't find what it is looking for.

Comment: Don't forget do include "tbody" as show in the source example.

Answer (score 23):

The following code works

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddRow()
{
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>test 2</td></tr>')
}
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" onclick="AddRow()"/>
<a href="">test</a>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody >
    <tr>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Note [this will work as of jQuery 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904232/132599) even if the table includes a `<tbody>` element:

> jQuery since version 1.4(?) automatically detects if the element you are trying to insert (using any of the append(), prepend(), before(), or after() methods) is a `<tr>` and inserts it into the first `<tbody>` in your table or wraps it into a new `<tbody>` if one doesn't exist.

Comment: and following can be used too
    var value1 = 1;
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + value1+'</td></tr>')

Answer (score 11):

I always use this code below for more readable

```
$('table').append([
'<tr>',
    '<td>My Item 1</td>',
    '<td>My Item 2</td>',
    '<td>My Item 3</td>',
    '<td>My Item 4</td>',
'</tr>'
].join(''));
```

or if it have `tbody`

```
$('table').find('tbody').append([
'<tr>',
    '<td>My Item 1</td>',
    '<td>My Item 2</td>',
    '<td>My Item 3</td>',
    '<td>My Item 4</td>',
'</tr>'
].join(''));
```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this is the answer you are looking for. It finds the last instance of `<tr />` and appends the new row after it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr class="child"><td>blahblah<\/td></tr>');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should append to the table and not the rows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').click(function() {
    $('#myTable').append('<tr class="child"><td>blahblah<\/td></tr>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: ok, you are doing something else wrong, please check here (http://secretgeek.net/rtjqe/realtimejqueryeditor.htm) your own code with my solution or dominic solution you will see that works.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```js
$("#myTable").append("<tr><%= escape_javascript( render :partial => name_of_partial ) %></tr>");
```

And in the `partial`, you should have:

```html
<td>row1</td>
<td>row2</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Add as first row or last row in a table**

To add as first row in table

```
$(".table tbody").append("<tr><td>New row</td></tr>");
```

To add as last row in table

```
$(".table tbody").prepend("<tr><td>New row</td></tr>");
```