# Insert a row in a table JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to insert a row on a specific place in the table. The user will input a number where he/she wants the row to be inserted.

Let's say that the user wants the row to be inserted on the second row of the tbody of the table.

```
<tr>
    <td>00001</td>
    <td>John</td>
</tr>
```

The table I have

```
<tr>
    <td>00002</td>
    <td>David</td>
</tr>
        <!-- Here is where I want it to be insterted -->
<tr>
    <td>00004</td>
    <td>Frank</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>00005</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes. yuo can with the help of jquery.

Comment: Please provide your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append rows to a table using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160890/how-do-you-append-rows-to-a-table-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach could be by adding a method in jquery prototype object for example:

```js
// a method to add row after specific row
$.prototype.addTableRowAfter = function(row, element) {
  // here you can modify it to a more general approach
  this.find('tr:eq(' + row + ')').after(element);
  return this;
};

// call it
$('table').addTableRowAfter(0, '<tr><td> 00001</td><td>John</td ></tr>');
$('table').addTableRowAfter(2, '<tr><td> 00003</td><td>Jim</td ></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>00002</td>
      <td>David</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Here is where I want it to be insterted -->
    <tr>
      <td>00004</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>00005</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to insert html, 
and to insert in the right place you can use CSS pseudo-class [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```
$("table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)").after('<tr><td>Example</td></tr>');
```

In my example you insert after the second tr tag.

Comment: That is wrong. The code insert html into target `tr`. You should use `.after()` instead of `.append()`

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `tr:first` element and than [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to add your new element:

```js
$('table tr:first').after('<tr><td>00001</td><td>John</td></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>00002</td>
    <td>David</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Here is where I want it to be insterted -->
  <tr>
    <td>00004</td>
    <td>Frank</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>00005</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what if I wanted the row to be inserted as the first row of the table?

Comment: @AyakoS to do that: `$('#table').prepend('<tr><td>00001</td><td>John</td></tr>');`