# Set focus on specific cell of last row of a table when text box value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

***What I wanted to do !!***

I have a one text-box on page, on page load focus will be set into text-box i will scan one item and it's digits will be inserted into text-box.Based on values it will add one row in html table.At the same time i wanted set focus on "CODE" cell text-box.

So every time I scan something it will insert a row into below table and every time i wanted to set focus on cell of CODE column of last row.Here in code column we will scan the value and it will be displayed on the same cell.

Further more if possible I wanted to set focus back to the text-box after scanning value in code cell value.So basically its back and forth scanning process.

```html
<input type="text" name=" " value=" ">
<br>
<div class="t-Report-tableWrap">
  <table class="t-Report-report" summary="Text Test">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead"  align="center"  id="DERIVED$01" >&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead"  align="center"  id="C003" >Id</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead"  align="center"  id="C001" >Name</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead"  align="center"  id="C002" >Code</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead"  align="center"  id="C007" >Text</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="init_row_invoice" style="display:none;" >
        <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="DERIVED$01">
          <a href ="javascript:void();" class="fa fa-trash-o"></a>
        </td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C003">(null)</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C001">(null)</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C002">
          <label for="f02_0000" id="f02_0000_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
          <input type="text" name="f02" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text" id="f02_0000" />
        </td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="C007">
          <label for="f03_0000" id="f03_0000_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
          <input type="text" name="f03" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text" id="f03_0000" />
          <input type="hidden" name="f01" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden" id="f01_0000" />
          <input type="hidden" name="f04" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden" id="f04_0000" />
          <input type="hidden" id="fcs_0000" name="fcs" value="">
          <input type="hidden" id="fcud_0000" name="fcud" value="D" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="DERIVED$01">
          <a href ="javascript:void(1);" class="fa fa-trash-o"></a>
        </td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C003">90001</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C001">Samsung Galaxy J3 Pro</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="C002">
          <label for="f02_0001" id="f02_0001_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
          <input type="text" name="f02" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="123456" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text" id="f02_0001" />
        </td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="C007">
          <label for="f03_0001" id="f03_0001_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
          <input type="text" name="f03" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="1" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text" id="f03_0001" />
          <input type="hidden" name="f01" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden" id="f01_0001" />
          <input type="hidden" name="f04" value="1" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden" id="f04_0001" />
          <input type="hidden" id="fcs_0001" name="fcs" value="9F677BEDD6F6624C586A9DA8BB60AA3DC1746ED2">
          <input type="hidden" id="fcud_0001" name="fcud" value="U" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="t-Report-links"></div>
<table class="t-Report-pagination t-Report-pagination--bottom" role="presentation">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="9" align="right" >
      <table role="presentation" >
        <tr>
          <td class="pagination"></td>
          <td class="pagination"></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap" class="pagination">
            <span class="t-Report-paginationText">1 - 3</span>
          </td>
          <td class="pagination"></td>
          <td class="pagination"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

***To be more clear.***

Scan value from a sticker it will insert value into text-box and it will add a rwo into table now same time it will set focus to cell column CODE of last row of here again we will scan value from sticker and after scanning it should set focus back to the textbox.

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160890/how-do-you-append-rows-to-a-table-using-jquery

Comment: @HemaNandagopal i got stuck at setting focus. i can append the rows.

Comment: While adding have you tried $('#C002').focus(); ?

Comment: C002 is for th and for table cell it's f02_0001 so i have tried this $('#f02_0001 ').focus(); as i wanted to set focus on cell but no luck

Comment: $("'#f02_0001 input").focus(); how about setting the focus to the input?

Comment: this also does not focus $("#f02_0001 input").focus();

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('table.t-Report-report')
  .find('tr')
  .last()
  .find('input[type="text"]')
  .first()
  .focus();

$('input').first().focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name=" " value=" "><br>
<div class="t-Report-tableWrap">
<table class="t-Report-report" summary="Text Test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="t-Report-colHead"  align="center"  id="DERIVED$01" >&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="t-Report-colHead"  align="center"  id="C003" >Id</th>
      <th class="t-Report-colHead"  align="center"  id="C001" >Name</th>
      <th class="t-Report-colHead"  align="center"  id="C002" >Code</th>
      <th class="t-Report-colHead"  align="center"  id="C007" >Text</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="init_row_invoice" style="display:none;" >
      <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="DERIVED$01"><a href ="javascript:void();" class="fa fa-trash-o"></a></td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="C003">(null)</td>
      <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="C001">(null)</td>
      <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="C002"><label for="f02_0000" id="f02_0000_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label><input type="text" name="f02" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text " id="f02_0000" /></td>
      <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="C007"><label for="f03_0000" id="f03_0000_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label><input type="text" name="f03" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text "  id="f03_0000" /><input type="hidden" name="f01" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden "  id="f01_0000" /><input type="hidden" name="f04" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden "  id="f04_0000" /><input type="hidden" id="fcs_0000" name="fcs" value=""><input type="hidden" id="fcud_0000" name="fcud" value="D" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="DERIVED$01"><a href ="javascript:void(1);" class="fa fa-trash-o"></a></td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="C003">90001</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="C001">Samsung Galaxy J3 Pro</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="C002"><label for="f02_0001" id="f02_0001_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label><input type="text" name="f02" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="123456" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text "  id="f02_0001" /></td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="C007">
          <label for="f03_0001" id="f03_0001_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
          <input type="text" name="f03" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="1" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text " id="f03_0001" />
          <input type="hidden" name="f01" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden "  id="f01_0001" /><input type="hidden" name="f04" value="1" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden "  id="f04_0001" /><input type="hidden" id="fcs_0001" name="fcs" value="9F677BEDD6F6624C586A9DA8BB60AA3DC1746ED2"><input type="hidden" id="fcud_0001" name="fcud" value="U" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="t-Report-links"></div>
  <table class="t-Report-pagination t-Report-pagination--bottom" role="presentation"><tr><td colspan="9" align="right" ><table role="presentation" ><tr><td class="pagination"></td><td class="pagination"></td><td nowrap="nowrap" class="pagination"><span class="t-Report-paginationText">1 - 3</span></td><td class="pagination"></td><td class="pagination"></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This looks nice i went for [name=f02].last.focus(); and it worked now only second part remains after you set value in CODE cell set focus back to text field

Comment: @PranavShah Which text field you are talking about, I'm bit confuse now. Are you talking about the top input textbox?

Comment: Here you go with the solution `$('input').first().focus();`. I've updated the answer as well.

Comment: where this will focus !!

Comment: @PranavShah This will focus the first input textbox that is present on top of the table.

Comment: Umm.. what i really want is set focus back after cell have some value on page load i can also do the same.
please check "To be more clear" part of my question

Answer (score 0):

With Length > 0

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn_process', function() {
  var tr = $('#init_row_invoice').clone(true);
  $('table.t-Report-report tbody').append(tr.show());
  $(tr).find('input[type=text][name=f03]').val('123');
  if ($(tr).find('input[type=text][name=f03]').val().length > 0) {
    $(tr).find('input[type=text][name=f02]').focus();
  } else {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name=" " value=" "><input id="btn_process" type="submit" value="process" /?<br>
<div class="t-Report-tableWrap">
  <table class="t-Report-report" summary="Text Test">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="DERIVED$01">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="C003">Id</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="C001">Name</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="C002">Code</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="C007">Text</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="init_row_invoice" style="display:none;">
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="DERIVED$01">
          <a href="javascript:void();" class="fa fa-trash-o"></a>
        </td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C003">(null)</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C001">(null)</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C002"><label for="f02_0000" id="f02_0000_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label><input type="text" name="f02" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text " id="f02_0000" /></td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C007">
          <label for="f03_0000" id="f03_0000_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
          <input type="text" name="f03" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text " id="f03_0000" />
          <input type="hidden" name="f01" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden " id="f01_0000" />
          <input type="hidden" name="f04" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden " id="f04_0000" />
          <input type="hidden" id="fcs_0000" name="fcs" value=""><input type="hidden" id="fcud_0000" name="fcud" value="D" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="DERIVED$01">
          <a href="javascript:void(1);" class="fa fa-trash-o"></a>
        </td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C003">90001</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C001">Samsung Galaxy J3 Pro</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C002"><label for="f02_0001" id="f02_0001_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label><input type="text" name="f02" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="123456" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text " id="f02_0001" /></td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C007"><label for="f03_0001" id="f03_0001_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label><input type="text" name="f03" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="1" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text " id="f03_0001" /><input type="hidden" name="f01" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden "
            id="f01_0001" /><input type="hidden" name="f04" value="1" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden " id="f04_0001" /><input type="hidden" id="fcs_0001" name="fcs" value="9F677BEDD6F6624C586A9DA8BB60AA3DC1746ED2"><input type="hidden" id="fcud_0001"
            name="fcud" value="U" />
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="t-Report-links"></div>
<table class="t-Report-pagination t-Report-pagination--bottom" role="presentation">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="9" align="right">
      <table role="presentation">
        <tr>
          <td class="pagination"></td>
          <td class="pagination"></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap" class="pagination"><span class="t-Report-paginationText">1 - 3</span></td>
          <td class="pagination"></td>
          <td class="pagination"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With Length == 0

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn_process', function() {
  var tr = $('#init_row_invoice').clone(true);
  $('table.t-Report-report tbody').append(tr.show());
  $(tr).find('input[type=text][name=f03]').val('');
  if ($(tr).find('input[type=text][name=f03]').val().length > 0) {
    $(tr).find('input[type=text][name=f02]').focus();
  } else {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name=" " value=" "><input id="btn_process" type="submit" value="process" /?<br>
<div class="t-Report-tableWrap">
  <table class="t-Report-report" summary="Text Test">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="DERIVED$01">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="C003">Id</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="C001">Name</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="C002">Code</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="C007">Text</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="init_row_invoice" style="display:none;">
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="DERIVED$01">
          <a href="javascript:void();" class="fa fa-trash-o"></a>
        </td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C003">(null)</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C001">(null)</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C002"><label for="f02_0000" id="f02_0000_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label><input type="text" name="f02" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text " id="f02_0000" /></td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C007">
          <label for="f03_0000" id="f03_0000_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
          <input type="text" name="f03" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text " id="f03_0000" />
          <input type="hidden" name="f01" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden " id="f01_0000" />
          <input type="hidden" name="f04" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden " id="f04_0000" />
          <input type="hidden" id="fcs_0000" name="fcs" value=""><input type="hidden" id="fcud_0000" name="fcud" value="D" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="DERIVED$01">
          <a href="javascript:void(1);" class="fa fa-trash-o"></a>
        </td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C003">90001</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C001">Samsung Galaxy J3 Pro</td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C002"><label for="f02_0001" id="f02_0001_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label><input type="text" name="f02" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="123456" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text " id="f02_0001" /></td>
        <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="C007"><label for="f03_0001" id="f03_0001_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label><input type="text" name="f03" size="15" maxlength="2000" value="1" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text " id="f03_0001" /><input type="hidden" name="f01" value="" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden "
            id="f01_0001" /><input type="hidden" name="f04" value="1" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--hidden " id="f04_0001" /><input type="hidden" id="fcs_0001" name="fcs" value="9F677BEDD6F6624C586A9DA8BB60AA3DC1746ED2"><input type="hidden" id="fcud_0001"
            name="fcud" value="U" />
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="t-Report-links"></div>
<table class="t-Report-pagination t-Report-pagination--bottom" role="presentation">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="9" align="right">
      <table role="presentation">
        <tr>
          <td class="pagination"></td>
          <td class="pagination"></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap" class="pagination"><span class="t-Report-paginationText">1 - 3</span></td>
          <td class="pagination"></td>
          <td class="pagination"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Check the length like:

```
$(tr).find('input[type=text][name=f03]').val().length > 0
```

Set focus

```
$(tr).find('input[type=text][name=f02]').focus();
```

Comment: is there any way we can check if name=f02 last cell value length > 0 if yes then again set focus back to the text field 
i have tried this but no luck
jQuery('#mytableid tbody').find('td:eq(3)').last().length();

Comment: how to do the same i dont know .... even i tried to get focused cell value length as it will be always last then if len > 0 then set focus back on text box

Comment: @PranavShah: Please check my updated code. You can write code to focus your required control `if length == 0` in `else {}`.