# How to add table rows to html table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, rows

I am new to JQuery and I am trying to append rows to an existing table.

1. What is wrong about the code?
2. How can I insert an empty row without specifying the values in the columns?
3. Is there a better way to do this? How?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var tbl = $('#mytable');
    appendTableRow(tbl)
  });
  
  function appendTableRow(table) {      
   var newrow = '';

   newrow += "<tr>";
   newrow += "<td>21</td>";
   newrow += "<td>22</td>";
   newrow += "</tr>";
       
   table.find('tbody tr:last').append(newrow);     
  }
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }

 table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }  
  
  table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
   <thead>
  <th>Col1</th>
  <th>Col2</th>
   </thead>
   
   <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Do not append to table row, so **NOT** `table.find('tbody tr:last').append(newrow); `, but to table body: `table.find('tbody').append(newrow); `.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append rows to a table using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160890/how-do-you-append-rows-to-a-table-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. Just append to tbody.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var tbl = $('#mytable');
    appendTableRow(tbl)
  });
  
  function appendTableRow(table) {      
   var newrow = '';

   newrow += "<tr>";
   newrow += "<td>21</td>";
   newrow += "<td>22</td>";
   newrow += "</tr>";
       
   $('tbody').append(newrow);     
  }
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }

 table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }  
  
  table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
   <thead>
  <th>Col1</th>
  <th>Col2</th>
   </thead>
   
   <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Nothing is *wrong*, it's doing what it's written to do. Programmatically, it's working fine.

*(I almost feel this is a trick question)*

**2)** Instead of `newrow += "<td>21</td>";` use `newrow += "<td> </td>";` ?

**3)** Is there a better way to do this? How?

^ These types of questions are off-topic on here.

Comment: This was not a trick question! If you run the code you will see that no new row was created. The two cells created were join next to the 1st row.